# Cannot start hadoop "localhost: nice: cannot set niceness"

Tags: windows-10, hadoop, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nice

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.9.0/logs/hadoop-ha-namenode-root.out
localhost: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.9.0/logs/hadoop-ha-datanode-root.out
localhost: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.9.0/logs/hadoop-ha-secondarynamenode-root.out
0.0.0.0: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
```

My system is Windows 10. I download Ubuntu from the store and tried to set up hadoop. But it doesn't work when I type in `sbin/start-dfs.sh`

Comment: You're getting the complaint a no -root user gets when trying to set a negative value for nice.  What are you trying to do with nice?  What is the actual command?

Comment: As I said, my commend is sbin/start-dfs.sh. Actually, this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782731/hadoop-permission-denied-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows. that one also doesn't have a solution.

Comment: Does your environment set HADROOP_NICENESS to a negative value?  Check with echo $HADROOP_NICENESS

Comment: Hi there, I check echo $HADOOP_NICENESS, but there is no value showing on the screen, does it mean I didn't set Hadoop niceness? Where I can set up this value? Thanks

Comment: HADROOP_NICENESS should default to 0 if it's not set, but check your scripts for that.  Try export HADROOP_NICENESS=1  then try your script to see if explicitly starting with a positive value keeps the negative assignment for happening.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can see this answer: https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/issues/695#issuecomment-386121530.
It says "You can safely ignore this warning. It's an upstream bug in Microsoft Windows."